# Forwarding arguments to constructor along with additional args

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to do the following:

```
template<typename T, typename Handle, typename... Args>
bool MyClass::CreateArray(T *&array_, Handle *&handle_, const std::string& 
                          handleName_, int64_t size_, int64_t startID_,Args... args)
{
   array_ = ns::makearray<T>(_segment,size_,CACHELINE_SIZE, startID_, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
   handle_ = ns::construct<Handle>(array_);

}

namespace ns {

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T *makearray(mem &segment, size_t size, size_t alignment, int64_t startID, Args... args )
{
    void* ptr = segment.alloc(sizeof(T) * size, alignment);

    //verify alignment
    assert((static_cast<char*>(ptr)-static_cast<char*>(0)) % alignment == 0);

    T* tPtr = static_cast<T*>(ptr);
    T* itr = tPtr;

    for(int64_t i=0; i< size; ++i)
    {
        T* obj = startID ? new (itr) T(i+startingID, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
                         : new (itr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        ++itr;
    }
    return tPtr;
}
}
```

use:

```
CreateArray<Widget,WidgetHandle>(_array,_arrayHandle,_arrayname,_size,_startingId,_widgettype);
//startingID is int64_t and widgettype is int32_t

class Widget
{
  public:

     Widget::Widget(int64_t id, int32_t type)
     {
        ...
     }
};
```

I'm getting the following compiler error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘ns::Widget::Widget(int)’

```
         T* obj = startID ? new (itr) T(i+startingID, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
```

It's not matching my 2 arg constructor. Seems to be ignoring the `(i+startingID)`. 
Can you not add additional arguments along with forwarding?

Comment: if you would create a [MCVE] that would really help us help you. I expect to copy paste your code in a compiler and see the problem for myself. Instead I get "use of undeclared identifier 'MyClass'". Please create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

You code is incomplete. This forces us to make assumptions about the missing parts of your code.

> ```
>   T* obj = startID ? new (itr) T(i+startingID, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
>                          : new (itr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
> ```

Assuming that `args...` is `widgettype` and `T` is `Widget` then the code expands after substitution to:

```
new (itr) Widget(i + startingID, widgettype)
```

and

```
new (itr) Widget(widgettype)
```

For the code to be valid then both `Widget(i + startingID, widgettype)` and `Widget(widgettype)` must be valid. You show just a `Widget::Widget(int64_t id, int32_t type)` ctor. If you don't have a ctor accepting `int32_t` argument then the code isn't valid.

This is what the error message tells you:

> no matching function for call to ‘ns::Widget::Widget(int)’

You might be confused because the error message might be placed at the beginning of of the full expression containing the error - the first line of the assignment, but it fact it comes from the second line, the `new (itr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` Again this is an educated guess, as you haven't provided a MCVE.